# Delay before drop-down menu disappears

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, hover

I've managed to create a drop-down menu using CSS and HTML. The drop-down menu will appear when mouse-hovered.

I want the drop-down menu to disappear 1 second after the mouse is hovered out. For this, I've tried adding

```
transition: display 1s;
```

into `.dropdown:hover .dropdown_list, .dropdown_list:hover` but it doesn't do anything.

**My Code:**

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
header {
    position: fixed;
    height: 35px;
    width: 100%;
    background: black;
}
.top-container {
    margin-top: 7px;
}
/* Code for drop-down list */
 .dropdown {
    margin-left: 100px;
    display: inline-block;
    color: #FFF;
}
.dropdown:hover {
    text-shadow:0px 4px 7px white;
}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown_list,
.dropdown_list:hover {
    display: block;
    top:100%;
    
    transition: display 1s; /* Doesn't work */
}
.dropdown_list {
    list-style: none;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    color: red;
    width: 100px;
}
.dropdown_list li {
    background: yellow;
}
li {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="top-container">
            <div class="dropdown">Dropdown &#10097;
                <ul class="dropdown_list">
                    <li>item 1</li>
                    <li>item 2</li>
                    <li>item 3</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
</body>
```

How do I make a one second delay for the drop-down menu to disappear after hovering out? Is this possible without any jQuery or Javascript?

Comment: `Display` property is not supported by transitions. Instead i would insist to you use `height:0px;` to `heigth:xx px;` for transition effects.

Comment: @divy3993 Ok. Could you tell me why [this](http://jsfiddle.net/rztxoc9u/) fails as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transition only applies to properties with numerical values. Display uses discrete values, so it cannot receive any transition effects.

With just CSS you can use `top` or similar properties to 'hide' the drop-down menu ([jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9t0m7sjd/5/)).

```
.dropdown:hover .dropdown_list,
.dropdown_list:hover {
    top: 100%;
    transition: none;
}
.dropdown_list {
    top: -10000%;
    display: block;
    transition: top 1s step-end;
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Ryan for highlighting this important condition for transitions to work i.e. Works on only properties with *Numerical* values